# Linear holomorphic function at infinity

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I have this exercise to solve:

> Let $f$ be entire and injective. Prove: There is an $F: \mathbb C^*
>  \rightarrow \mathbb C^*$ such that $F$ holomorphic and $F(z)=f(z)$ for
> $z \neq \infty$.

I have proven already in the first part of this exercise that there is some $a, b\in \mathbb C, a \ne 0$ such that $f(z)=az+b$.

I have trouble solving this now, it seems not possible to me.

Holomorphic at infinity means that $F(1/z)$ is holomorphic at $0$. Since around $0$ we have $F=f$, this condition becomes $f(1/z)$ holomorphic at $0$, which is clearly not true, since $f(1/z)=a \cdot \frac 1 z + b$ has a pole at $0$. Am I misunderstanding the task?

Edit: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4702488/understanding-proof-for-holomorphic-function) is a link to the first part of the exercise.

Comment: Since $\infty\not\mathbb{C}$, I don't understand the meaning of "$F(z)=f(z)$ for $z\ne\infty$.

Comment: I guess it just means for all $z\in \mathbb C$ we have $F(z)=f(z)$. The $z\ne \infty$ was added because it's in the definition set of $F$ I guess.

Comment: Then what about simply defining $F(z)$ as $f(z)$? And what is the injectivity of $f$ needed for?

Comment: The injectivity was needed to prove that you can write $f(z)$ as $az+b$ as said. But when you just set $F(z)$ as $f(z)$, then you don't have holormorphy at $\infty$, do you? I have added a link btw

Comment: Which definition of holomorphy at $\infty$ are you using?

Comment: You're missing a definition of holomorphy for functions that have $\infty$ as a value.  In the spirit of the $F(1/z)$ definition for holomorphy at $\infty$, for functions with $F(p) = \infty$ you want $1/F(z)$ to be holomorphic at $p$.  For $F(\infty) = \infty$, you want $1/F(1/z)$ to be holomorphic at $0$.

Answer (score 1):

So, the reason you are confused, which is entirely justified, is the fact that this exercise uses the word "holomorphic" somewhat loosely. You will probably know the term "meromorphic", which is holomorphic except for some isolated poles. Historically they didn't want to differentiate any of this, since poles and zeros are simply the exact same if viewed from a different angle as follows:
Consider $\mathbb{C}^*=\mathbb{C}\cup \{\infty\}$ as a topological manifold, where the topology is the same as on $\mathbb{C}$ and a basis around $\infty$ is given by the complement of any compact set. Then $\mathbb{C}^*$ is homeomorphic to the sphere in 3 dimensions. One such map and homeomorphism is the stereographic projection, which maps the north pole of the sphere to inifinity, while the south pole of the sphere is mapped to $0$. But analysis on the sphere should not at all depend on rotations, or at least you can easily see that everything works out the same no matter how the sphere is rotated, no matter which point is supposed to "be infinity". So historically they used to think of holomorphic maps as analytic maps from the sphere to itself, which are simply analytic maps from $\mathbb{C}^*$ to $\mathbb{C}^*$. For this point of view there is no difference between meromorphic and holomorphic, or more precisely: There is no reason to make up a word for "meromorphic", because it is essentially the same as holomorphic with a zero, if you rotate/reflect the sphere, which, on $\mathbb{C}^*$, is just the reflection $z\mapsto \frac{1}{z}$.